# Find all the cluster points for the following

Tags: real-analysis

**Problem:** Write all the cluster points of the set

$$
 A = (-1)^n: \quad\forall
n\in\mathbb N 
$$

I'm puzzled. I don't know how I can find them aren't there too many?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is the definition of cluster point you have in mind?

Comment: A point $x∈R$ is called a cluster point of set A subset of R if every neighborhood V of $x$ contains an element a∈A different from $x$

Comment: @Bcpicao is it only 1????

Comment: I will add this as a comment as maybe I am just unfamiliar. I would think $A=\{-1,1\}$ and so there are no cluster points in this set. What the answer below to me is describing is a convergent subsequence. The definition of cluster point requires that there be a point different from $x$ from the set within every arbitrary neighborhood of $x$. Take the neighborhood with radius $\varepsilon=1/2$ about $x=1$, there are no other points from $A$ different from $1$ within that neighborhood.

Comment: @Frudrururu, exactly!

Comment: That is exactly why I inquired about your definition of cluster point! The canonical definition of a cluster point of a sequence is exactly that it is the limit point of a subsequence, meaning it is under no obligation to differ from the values of the sequence themselves. In this optic, @Connor_Tracy’s answer is indeed correct. The definition @Frudrururu is using is that of a cluster point of a topological space, for which, of course, to avoid redundancy, the other points in the neighborhood must be distinct.

Comment: @Bcpicao thank you so much for your time and effort, i'll be careful next time to attach the definitions/theorems I'm studying. have a wonderful day.

Comment: Not an issue! You too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence $\left( -1\right)^n$ alternates between $-1$ and $+1$. Every odd $n$ gives $-1$ and every even $n$ gives $+1$. So there are infinitely many $n$ such that the sequence is equal to either of these values, so they are both cluster points. Conversely, these are the only two discrete values of the sequence so there are no other values that could possibly be cluster points other than $\pm 1$.

Stay safe

Comment: thank you so much for your time. I hope you have a nice day, stay safe too.

Comment: No worries! I’m glad I could help. Have a great day!